# Cocoa - Pass parameter for setAction

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I thought I'd try my hand at creating a simple cocoa app.  It is a simple inbox notifier for reddit.  I am bringing in a bunch of URLs and would like to make menu items for each URL with a link to the page. I 'd like to set the actions of each, dynamically. I need to pass the URL to the method, so it knows where to go.  I have a feeling I am doing this all wrong.  Can someone point me in the right direction.  I'd like to just create an NSURL and send it to loadMessage.

```
NSURL *tempURL   = [NSURL  URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.reddit.com%@", [[message objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"context"]]];

[temptItem setAction:@selector(loadMessage:messageUrl:)];
```

Answer (score 1):

That selector isn't a valid action message. Actions can accept either one argument or none; if they accept one argument, the object passed in the argument will be the control that sent the message.

What you need to do is create a method in your controller that calls your `loadMessage:messageURL:` method with the correct objects.

Comment: OK, but how would I associate the URL with each menu item?

Answer (score 1):

As Chuck said, that selector has the wrong form. One way to do it is to use `-representedObject` to e.g. associate the item with an URL:

```
- (void)menuAction:(id)sender {
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[sender representedObject]]; 
}

// adding an item:
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com/"];    
NSMenuItem *item = [[[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"moo" 
                    action:@selector(menuAction:) keyEquivalent:@""] autorelease];
[item setTarget:self];
[item setRepresentedObject:url];
[item setEnabled:YES];    
// insert into menu
```

Comment: I tried this and although it doesn't error out it doesn't quite work, either.  I tried your suggestion with the following method declaration.
[code]


-(IBAction)menuLoadMessage:(id)sender{
 [self loadMessage:[sender representedObject]];
}

-(void)loadMessage:(NSURL *)messageUrl{
 [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:messageUrl];
}

[/code]

Comment: @user: Did you use `-setRepresentedObject:` on the items?

Comment: NSURL           *tempURL   = [NSURL  URLWithString:
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.reddit.com%@", [[message objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"context"]]];
  
[tempItem setRepresentedObject:tempURL];
[tempItem setAction:@selector(menuLoadMessage:)];

Comment: user312867: Is that code running (i.e., is the method/block/compound statement it's in being called)? Have you verified that `tempItem` is not `nil`?

Comment: Nice.  Ok that worked.  I wasn't setting the target of the to self.  What is the logic behind doing that?  I am sorry.....so new to this...

Comment: @user: The instance of menu-item doesn't know what instance creates it. Even if it did, we do not always want it to call `self`, we might set different objects as targets - e.g. `-terminate:` on `NSApp` when *"Quit"* was clicked.